# How to calculate pairwise distances of nominal variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame where I need to calculate pairwise differences between all rows(names here).

```
names<- c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8")
v1 <- c(2,3,4,2,2,4,7,12)
v2 <- c(15,12,2,2,3,1,7,12) 
v3<- c(2,3,2,16,14,11,2,7)
v4<- c(12,3,4,5,9,1,12,13)

mydf<- data.frame(names,v1,v2,v3,v4)
```

So the expected output needs to be something similar to what dist(mydf[-1]) gives but those numbers are nominal characters and the order of values also matter. 
e.g: "t1 and "t2" are 4/4 different while "t1" & "t3" difference is 3/4.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: A data frame (matrix) with names as rows and cols->> diagonal=0

Comment: Please show your expected output in the post by editing it as we don't know what you want

Comment: Would `dist(mydf[-1])` do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
ans <- expand.grid(first=1:nrow(mydf), second=1:nrow(mydf))

ans$diff <- apply(ans, 1, function(x) {
    ncols <- ncol(mydf)-1
    sum(mydf[x[1],-1] != mydf[x[2],-1]) / ncols
})

m <- matrix(ans$diff, nrow = nrow(mydf))
colnames(m) <- rownames(m) <- names
m
```

Comment: not actually, these are nominal values not continuous variables

Comment: So you want an output like "3/4"?

Comment: And as you mentioned above, you wanted "0" in the diagonal

Comment: well if it is the upper.tri the zeros will be omitted.

Comment: Yes. Anyway, now the output is nominal.

Comment: great. Can we change the code so that it works for any number of columns instead of 4?

Comment: well the output does not need to be nominal, the input data should be treated as nominal as apposed to continuous.

Comment: The solution works even if the input is nominal. Try converting v1, v2, etc. to characters and you'll see.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The fact that you put '/' make it hard when I want to convert it to csv. Those values (2/10) are saved as dates in Excel!

Comment: You told me you wanted that format. I can't guess you want to export it to Excel. What about if we change it to "3 out of 4" or something like that?

Comment: sorry about that! I just want the 3/4 as a number, not a character!

Comment: So 0.75 instead of "3/4"?

Comment: OK... now the solution returns a numerical matrix

Comment: @spadarian Hi, could you please tell what does mydf[x[1],-1] did here? Since there were no "x" in the dataframe, I cannot quite undertand it